# Pointers outside of () statement

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I can't understand whats going on inside of the loop

```
char var_64;
char var_24;
int32_t r0_6 = 0;

do
{
   *(&var_24 + r0_6) = *(&var_64 + r0_6);
   r0_6 = r0_6 + 1;
}
while (r0_6 != 8);
```

I cant get this part:

```
*(&var_24 + r0_6) = *(&var_64 + r0_6);
```

does it take the address of var_24 increment it by 1 and assigned to it the address of var_64 incremented by 1?
and what does the pointer * do here?

**EDIT:**

Here is the same decompiled code from another decompiler:

```
 char v29[16];
 unsigned __int8 v39;
 memset(&v39, 0, 8u);
 memset(v29, 0, 0x10u);
 do
  {
    *(&v39 + v10) = v29[v10];
    ++v10;
  }
  while ( v10 != 8 );
```

Here I think it the same, but it shows the v29 as an array

Comment: `r0_6` isn't initialized, and it's accessing memory outside what is defined. So what you show would be undefined behavior. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If var_24 and var_64 were bytes in two memory regions, this could be copying part the var_64 region to the var_24 region.  But if they are individual chars and r0_6 is not initialized as you say, then it makes no sense.

Comment: Looks like it is corrupting the stack, or arbitrary memory, depending on the current value of r0_6.

Comment: This code is weird and even if `r0_6` was initialized properly code like `*(&var_24 + r0_6)` is undefined behaviour if `r0_6` is different from zero. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: With the names of the variables, it looks like some decompiler output.

Comment: Please let us know where this code comes from. If it is some decompiler output, it changes everything except that `r0_6` is not initialized, or did you omit some code between `int r0_6;` and `do {`

Comment: @Devolus yes it is decompiler's code, I have edited the questions and added the same decompiled code from another decompile

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes it is a decompiler's code, i have added the question where I have added the decompiled  the same decompiled code from another decompiler

Comment: Maybe the actual assembly code would be easier to understand...

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Definitly. With the assembly, or more context, it's hard to see what the code is assumed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char v29[16];
unsigned __int8 v39;
memset(&v39, 0, 8u);
memset(v29, 0, 0x10u);
do
{
    *(&v39 + v10) = v29[v10];
    ++v10;
}
while ( v10 != 8 );
```

Since this is decompiled code, I assume that the original code might looke like this:

```
{
    char v29[16];
    int8_t v39[8];

    memset(&v39, 0, sizeof (v39));
    memset(v29, 0, sizeof(v29));

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(v39); i++)
    {
        ((char *)(&v39))[i] = v29[i];
    }
}
```

Which would mean that you have an array of binary bytes, converted to a binary value, ignoring machine byte order, so it might be that this is only part of the code, or the array already is in the correct byte order.

The reason why v10 is not declared or initialized *MIGHT* be, that the compiler optimized code by reusing a register knowing that it has to be zero from the previous call to memset. But this is only an assumption.

The code is still pretty useless IMO, because the result will always be zero as the array is initialized with 0.

Comment: Sorry, the v10 is initialized as an integer: int v10; and it also returns the 0 from sub before the code i gave.

Comment: Hmm. It's not mentioned in the provided code though. :) Anyway, this doesn't really change much. r0_6 was also now initialized, which it wasn't before.

Comment: why you think that v39 declared as int64?

Comment: Because the compiled code took 8 bytes, so I was assuming that. Especially since the decompiler declared it as int8. I find the memset irratiting though, because that is usually not done by a compiler.

Comment: but int8 is an 8 bits value, no? and cant it be that  memset(&v39, 0, 8u); is something like clear the array therefore v39 can be an array of 8 bytes?

Comment: That could also be a valid interpretation. Since we have to guess, aynthing is ok, as long as it represents the snippet. Without seeing more context, it's hard to determine. Considerin that, it might even be more sensible. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're trying to use a variable `r0_6`, which

- has automatic storage and .not initialized.
- does not have it's address taken
- can have trap representation.

Then, at a later point of time, once you initialize the value of `r0_6`, you're essentially trying to dereference a memory location `*(&var_64 + r0_6)`, [when `r0_6` is anything but 0], which is not valid, which again invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In short, the code is pointless.

That said, in general, the syntax

```
 *(pointer -or- address)
```

indicates [indirection or dereference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator), that is dereferencing that memory location to arrive at the value at that location.